# How to change height of edit box associated with CMFCToolbarEditBoxButton

Tags: mfc-feature-pack

I would like to decrease the height of the edit box associated with a CMFCToolbarEditBoxButton on a CMFCToolBar.

I have been able to change successfully the height of a combo box associated with CMFCToolbarComboBoxButton by changing the font size after the ReplaceButton step in OnToolbarReset.

This approach doesn't work for CMFCToolbarEditBoxButton. (see CGuiEditBox section in the following code.)

The first code is from OnToolbarSet. I assign a font to the edit box. I even tried making the size of the font very small. It had no effect.

Next I tried to change the rectangle associated with the edit box in the toolbar's AdjustLocations method. That approach also was unsuccessful.

```
LRESULT CMainFrame::OnToolbarReset(WPARAM wp, LPARAM)
{
    UINT uiToolBarId = (UINT)wp;

    switch (uiToolBarId)
    {
    case IDR_TOPTOOLBAR_REG:
    {
        CZoomCombo ZoomCombo;
        ZoomCombo.EnableWindow(TRUE);

        ZoomCombo.SetDropDownHeight(300);
        ZoomCombo.SetCenterVert(TRUE);

        ZoomCombo.AddItem(_T(".5x"));
        ZoomCombo.AddItem(_T("1x"));
        ZoomCombo.AddItem(_T("2x"));
        ZoomCombo.AddItem(_T("3x"));
        ZoomCombo.AddItem(_T("4x"));
        ZoomCombo.AddItem(_T("5x"));
        ZoomCombo.AddItem(_T("6x"));
        ZoomCombo.AddItem(_T("7x"));
        ZoomCombo.AddItem(_T("8x"));
        ZoomCombo.AddItem(_T("9x"));
        ZoomCombo.AddItem(_T("10x"));

        m_wndTopToolBar.ReplaceButton(IDC_ZOOMCOMBO_DUMMY, ZoomCombo);

        do
        {
            CMFCToolBarButton* pButton = NULL;

            int nZoomIndex = m_wndTopToolBar.CommandToIndex(IDC_ZOOMCOMBO);

            if (nZoomIndex == -1)
                break;

            pButton = m_wndTopToolBar.GetButton(nZoomIndex);

            if (pButton == NULL)
            break;

            ASSERT(pButton->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton)));

            CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton* pComboButton = (CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton*)pButton;
            CComboBox* pCbo = pComboButton->GetComboBox();
            CEdit* pEdit    = pComboButton->GetEditCtrl();

            if (pCbo == NULL || pEdit == NULL)
            break;

            pCbo->SetFont(&m_ToolBarBtnFont);
            pEdit->SetFont(&m_ToolBarBtnFont);

            m_wndTopToolBar.InvalidateButton(nZoomIndex);

            int nSel = GetZoomComboIndex(m_Zoom);
            if (nSel >= 0)
            {
                pCbo->SetCurSel(nSel);

                CString str;
                pCbo->GetWindowText(str);
                pComboButton->SetText(str);
            }
        } while (false);

        //

        CGuiEditBox GuiEditBox;
        GuiEditBox.EnableWindow(TRUE);

        m_wndTopToolBar.ReplaceButton(IDC_GUIEDITBOX_DUMMY, GuiEditBox);

        do
        {
            CMFCToolBarButton* pButton = NULL;

            int nGuiIndex = m_wndTopToolBar.CommandToIndex(IDC_GUIEDITBOX);

            if (nGuiIndex == -1)
                break;

            pButton = m_wndTopToolBar.GetButton(nGuiIndex);

            if (pButton == NULL)
                break;

            ASSERT(pButton->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton)));

            CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton* pEditBoxButton = (CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton*)pButton;
            CEdit* pEdit = pEditBoxButton->GetEditBox();

            if (pEdit == NULL)
                break;

            pEdit->SetFont(&m_ToolBarBtnFont); // height of this font is much less than default

            //CFont* pFont = pEdit->GetFont();
            //LOGFONT lf;
            //pFont->GetLogFont(&lf);  // confirmed that font has been changed

            m_wndTopToolBar.InvalidateButton(nGuiIndex);

        } while (false);

    }
    break;
    }

    return 0;
}

//

void CMFCToolBarEx::AdjustLocations()
{
    CMFCToolBar::AdjustLocations();

    if (GetSafeHwnd())
    {
        CMFCToolBarButton* pButton = NULL;

        int nGuiIndex = CommandToIndex(IDC_GUIEDITBOX);
        if (nGuiIndex != -1)
        {
            pButton = GetButton(nGuiIndex);
            if (pButton)
            {
                ASSERT(pButton->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton)));

                CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton* pEditBoxButton = (CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton*)pButton;

                CEdit* pEdit = pEditBoxButton->GetEditBox();
                if (pEdit != NULL)
                {
                    CRect rPos;
                    pEdit->GetRect(&rPos);
                    rPos.DeflateRect(0, 4);
                    pEdit->SetRect(rPos);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I investigated the source code for afxtoolbareditboxbutton.cpp and saw that the height of the edit box is being set in the OnMove method by the following line

```
int cy = GetGlobalData()->GetTextHeight();
```

I changed that line in a subclass of CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton to resolve my problem.